# How to give background-image over background-color

Tags: html, css

I'm tried to give background-image over background-color, can anyone help.
Here's my code,

```css
.next {
    width: 40px;
 height: 45px;
 border-radius: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
 background-image: url(http://placehold.it/10x10);
        background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="next"></div>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand. Are you trying to overlay the image with some translucent color ?

Comment: your code is working perfect

Comment: Someone answered exactly what I want. @imsayan thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want, Try This

```css
.next {
 width: 40px;
 height: 45px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #fee8fe url(http://placehold.it/10x10) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<div class="next"></div>
```

Comment: Exact this I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background` instead of `background-image` & `background-color`. Check updated snippet

```css
.next {
    width: 40px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #fff url(http://placehold.it/10x10) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="next"></div>
```